# SQL: Difference between add unique and add unique index?

Tags: mysql, sql

Are these two exactly the same in terms of functionality?

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD UNIQUE ('column1', 'column2');
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD UNIQUE INDEX ('column1', 'column2');
```

Comment: What does a DESCRIBE statment say? Generally, in the manual keywords within square brackets are optional.

Comment: unique is also work as an index ,, so i think both are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - they are functionally identical.